# How do Leslie Weatherhead's views on the will of God compare to contemporary Baptist thought?

Tags: baptist, will-of-god

I am reading Leslie Weatherhead's collection of sermons on 'The Will of God' from [a book of the same title](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Will_of_God.html?id=8sDwbJdxpIgC) (ISBN: 9 780687 074822 published by Abingdon Press).

He looks at God's will in three ways -

1. God's intentional will which he sees as God's ideal purpose,
2. God's circumstantial will which he sees as God's will in the circumstances which evil has set up, and
3. God's ultimate will which he sees as God's final purpose to bring about his original will overcoming evil completely.

I would really like to know how Weatherhead's views on the will of God compare to contemporary Baptist thought on the same subject - specifically the views of mainstream British Baptists who are part of the Baptist Union of Great Britain. Are Weatherhead's and British Baptists' views compatible?  Are they at odds in certain aspects, and if so which? Are they very different?

Comment: Plenty clear. Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate.

Comment: I don't think I could comment on the specific perspectives being inquired of, but i imagine it will be something along the lines of Ephesians 1:11, "purpose of His will" and Phil 1:10, "good, acceptable, and perfect".  Not knowing this particular author, though, it would be interesting how he develops his classifications.  Interesting question though.

Answer (score 1):

Weatherhead pointed out that the New Testament never refers to Jesus as God and neither did Jesus refer to himself in this way. Jesus called himself the Son of Man and the Word. To say that Jesus was the "only begotten son" of God would be an impossibility, as such information is not presently available

The King James Bible stated in **John 10:25-30** *even to the end of the chapter, and I quote:

"25 Jesus answered them, I told you, and ye believed not: the works that I do in my Father's name, they bear witness of me.

26 But ye believe not, because ye are not of my sheep, as I said unto you.

27 My sheep hear my voice, and I know them, and they follow me:

28 And I give unto them eternal life; and they shall never perish, neither shall any man pluck them out of my hand.

29 My Father, which gave them me, is greater than all; and no man is able to pluck them out of my Father's hand.

30 I and my Father are one".*

***"They being one indicates that Christ is God incarnate in the flesh"***

Any and all teachers then or now, are only as good as the translation they use, if it is the Syrian text he does well . . . if it is the the Alexandrian (Egyptian text) it is . . . well you get the idea.